# How I can change cursor color in Vim's color scheme?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I use this color scheme: [Cobalt Colour scheme](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2828).

I cannot see the cursor in insert mode.

How I can change the cursor's color?

I think this is the cursor part:

```
hi CursorLine     guifg=none              guibg=#002943
hi Cursor         guifg=#F8F8F8           guibg=#A7A7A7
hi CursorIM       guifg=#F8F8F8           guibg=#002947"#5F5A60
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is quite a lot of information about how to set the insert mode cursor color in the [vim documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor)

Here is an example from the linked documentation:

```
highlight Cursor guifg=white guibg=black
highlight iCursor guifg=white guibg=steelblue
set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor
set guicursor+=i:ver100-iCursor
set guicursor+=n-v-c:blinkon0
set guicursor+=i:blinkwait10
```

EDIT:

The `i` means insert mode, `v` visual, `c` command, and `n` normal

Answer (score 37):

@GWW is right. But the example above only works for gvim, not vim. You'd better configure in `.vimrc` as in the same [documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) to make it work in xterm, for example:

```
if &term =~ "xterm\\|rxvt"
  " use an orange cursor in insert mode
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]12;orange\x7"
  " use a red cursor otherwise
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]12;red\x7"
  silent !echo -ne "\033]12;red\007"
  " reset cursor when vim exits
  autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\033]112\007"
  " use \003]12;gray\007 for gnome-terminal
endif
```

Comment: "ViM cannot change the color of your cursor; it will always be the color your terminal application decides to make it." https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72800/166686

Comment: @LiviuChircu This is not true. Some terminals like `xterm` allow it.