# How can I enable a see-through block cursor in vim/my terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal, text-editor

While in command mode in vim, I can't see through my cursor.

For example, the gibberish text 
`nuhsantoheun` renders as:

[image: cursor]

I can solve this by enabling a blinking cursor in my terminal emulator settings, however I'd like to find some sort of cursor that, rather than blinking, simply shows a highlighted or reverse-highlighted letter.

Comment: the solution below help me resolve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230490/how-i-can-change-cursor-color-in-color-scheme-vim

Answer (score 3):

Solved this while writing the question, so figured I might as well leave it up here to help out someone else.

In your terminal editor, simply set your cursor color to be something other than your text color, which produces the desired behavior:

[image]

Comment: I would say, you "created" this problem, instead of "solving" it.  Since it is "see-through" cursor by default.

Comment: @kent you're not wrong, i installed a terminal theme a while back and didn't know that i'd run into this problem.